# How to reference a (Dynamic Lib) DLL in a Visual Studio 2012 C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I made a dynamic library with compiled headers and compiled a DLL (using Visual Studio 2012).

I also have a C++ project made also with Visual Studio 2012 which i want to reference the previous DLL generated.

How to reference that (Dynamic Lib) DLL in my Visual Studio 2012 C++ project ? Does i also need to point the header file (.h) if i want to use the functions of the library ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it easiest to reference the DLL project using the `Framework and References` item in the project's properties dialog:

[image]

It looks like you're adding some weird .Net thing into your C++ native code, but it's also the easiest way for a native-code project to reference another.

If you want to call functions in that DLL, then yes, you probably want to include that DLL's header file.

Comment: This solution only works if the DLL was created in the same desktop environment. If you only have the DLL and the header (not the VS solution), then it's useless.

Comment: I might have the issue PhilMacKay writes about. Sadly "it's useless" doesn't help me figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this but all have in commmon that you need to include the header in your project so that the functions are known since C++ doesn't have reflection.

1. you can skip linking statically and load the dll using LoadLibrary and getting the functions using GetProcAddress, this has the advantage that you can make the DLL optional. If it is not there you could just avoid calling it or give some user friendly error message.
2. you can statically link to the dll, this means adding the .lib file of the dll to your project, there are a few ways to do this, the old school way is to add it in properties of your solution/linker/input/additional dependencies and then make sure the dll is in the exe search path. You will get an error message if it is not found.

Comment: Could i use #pragma comment( lib, "ws2_32.lib" ) liek syntax to achieve this too ?

Comment: What are the other ways to satically link the DLL?
LoadLibrary() looks promising, how different is is from using `#include header.h`?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.80).aspx (Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library)

Answer (score -1):

I can give you an answer about how to add dll in VS 2010

steps: 
right click on solution explorer, properties , configuration properties, General, output directory.
here press on right arrow and select brows.
brows to DLL directory.

thats all.

Comment: This does nothing to add an existing DLL to the project.